# Simplifying or improving a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The following code is executed before the model is saved. It checks a `has_many` association for change before looping through and setting a value on each. It checks through each answer option whether the `correct_answer` is changed on any of the answers. If so, it looks for which was changed and was `true`.

```
if self.answer_options.select{|a| a.correct_answer_changed?}.any?
  self.answer_options.each do |answer_option|
    if answer_option.correct_answer_changed? && !answer_option.correct_answer_was
      answer_option.correct_answer = true
    else
      answer_option.correct_answer = false
    end
  end
end
```

How could I simplify or improve this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the code you have shared is working, I would dry it up a bit as..

```
self.answer_options.map{|a| a if a.correct_answer_changed?}.compact.each do |answer_option|
  answer_option.toggle(:correct_answer)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
answer_options.each do |answer_option|
  answer_option.correct_answer =
    answer_option.correct_answer_changed? && !answer_option.correct_answer_was
end
if answer_options.all?{|answer_option| answer_option.correct_answer == false}
  answer_options.each{|answer_option| answer_option.correct_answer == nil}
end
```

Comment: `answer_options.each{|answer_option| answer_option.correct_answer == nil}` this looks weird, what are you trying to do here?

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon It reverts the `false` value assigned when there is no `answer_option` that satisfies `answer_option.correct_answer_changed?`. In the original code, there was a condition for that.